# Does socket.io rooms share variables?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

im making a tictactoe game with socket.io and nodejs

with `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`, you can get the room objects

i want to set a "board" variable to a room. this is what i tried:

```
var rooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms
var defaultBoard = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];  //the default tictactoe board. 1 is x, 2 is o
var roomCreated = 0;
io.on("connection", socket => {
  //this event is emitted when someone click the "Create game" button
  socket.on("createGame", () => {
    var roomToJoin = `room-${++roomCreated}`;
    socket.join(roomToJoin);
    rooms[roomToJoin][socket.id].myTurn = true // add a myTurn variable to the player
    rooms[roomToJoin].board = defaultBoard;
  })
  socket.on("joinGame", roomRequested => {
    if (rooms[roomRequested] && rooms[roomRequested].length === 1) {
      socket.join(roomRequested);
      rooms[roomRequested][socket.id].myTurn = false //add a myTurn variable to the joiner
      socket.emit("joined", rooms[roomRequested].board);
    }
  });
  socket.on("playTurn", (row, col => {                     //emited when client click a tile
    Object.entries(rooms).forEach(e => {                   //loop through each room
      if (e[1].sockets[socket.id] && e[1].board) {         //get the room the socket is in
        if (e[1].board[row][col] && !e[1][socket.id].myTurn) return;//if the tile is filled or not my turn, do nothing
        rooms[e[0]][socket.id].myTurn = !myTurn            //its not my turn anymore
        rooms[e[0]].otherPlayer.myTurn = !rooms[e[0]].otherPlayer.myTurn //otherPlayer is a variable i defined
        rooms[e[0]].board[row][col] = tile;                //change the tile of the board of the room (tile is a defined variable, could be 1 or 2)
       //let the client know the server updated his board, and update his html tictactoe board
        socket.emit("newBoard", room.board);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

the problem is, board is somehow shared between the room objects. even though i refreshed the page and create a new game, somehow i still see the same board.it was not a visual bug, i were sure because i logged the client room's board

if there are any syntax errors or such errors, its because i might have copied the code wrong. i didnt paste the full code in.

Comment: if the method i used to set a variable to a room is incorrect. can you tell me a working method?

Comment: You've assigned the `defaultBoard` by reference to each room's `board` property, so each time you modify a room's `board`, you're modifying `defaultBoard`.

Comment: `rooms[roomToJoin].board = defaultBoard.map(row => [...row]);` should fix it.